# Will dual wireless interfaces in Linux increase my bandwidth?

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, linux-kernel

I have two wireless interfaces connected to the same network.  Is it possible for data to be transferred on them simultaneously?

Comment: yes. can you please elaborate? What is the purpose? etc..

Comment: @u8sand The purpose is to get increased bandwidth.  What else is there to elaborate on?

Comment: it is indeed possible for data to be transferred simultaneously-through your network. But they all go through your router which shares bandwidth between your two interfaces so in the end you won't gain any bandwidth.

Comment: @u8sand ahh that makes sense.  What if I was connecting directly to a server on my network?  Is the Linux kernel smart enough to send and retrieve some of the packets on one interface and other packets on the other interface?

Comment: hmm, I haven't tried it. If the server also had two interfaces you might gain something out of it, but a similar idea to the router is that the server is also sharing bandwidth with its clients. (unless, this server was actually a group of computers that could provide you dedicated service, aka one server per interface) but your kernel will be performing "multi-tasking" with the two interfaces, with a multi core processor you just might benefit because of it.

Comment: If you use two different channels to connect to different machines directly, it would work.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible for data to be transmitted on them simultaneously, however unless they are connected to different access points I doubt you will an increase in speed (in fact, from discussions I had with a Wireless ISP a couple of weeks ago you are more likely to experience a decrease speed as they are competing for same frequency and causing noise for each other).

Also, combined simultaneous use is harder then just putting 2 cards in, you will need to either modify the card use (eg data being split out between the cards based on route or channel bonding the devices)  You will also need a mechanism for getting back through both interfaces which can be tricky.

I'd posit that its generally not worth doing this from a desktop.

Answer (score 0):

You would get more speed to local servers, but one interface will have a lower metric and therefore get precedence. In some apps you can specify which interface to use, though.

Comment: Not necessarily though - you could channel bond the interfaces and thus share the bandwidth.